# I have an custom AMI and want to run certain config commands at initial boot, depending on the autoscale instance that starts it. How do I do this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have a custom AMI that contains the dependencies for several applications.

The only difference between the applications is several configuration options that can be configured by a bash script. (i.e. enabling/disabling certain supervisor groups.)

Each different app is triggered by an different autoscale instance.

How do I get the instance to run a different script on boot by an autoscaler?

Answer (score 4):

If I am understanding you correctly, you have one AMI used in several autoscaling groups and want to run a specific “bootstrap” sequence on it depending on the autoscaling group it belongs to.

This is not difficult to accomplish because the [launch configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-launch-configuration.html) you created to map the autoscaling group to the AMI can [accomodate user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-launch-configuration.html) which can be a shell script.

In the shell script provided as user data, it is customary to [retrieve meta data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) so that the instances can correctly identify itself in logs and arrange other similar last minute details.  This meta-data could also contain a reference to the auto-scaling group, which you could take advantage of to reduce the little overhead due to autoscaling-group management.